# Problemas con tabla en Mysql y Xampp

Tags: mysql, oracle, xampp

En mi base de datos tengo esto con solo una tabla y mi problema surge cuando desde el administrador de phpMyAdmin al importar el archivo .sql me da el siguiente error.

```
Error
consulta SQL:


--
-- Table structure for table `alumno`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `alumno`
MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1046 - Base de datos no seleccionada
```

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.17, for Win64 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1    Database: cphpmysql
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.7.18-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `alumno`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `alumno`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `alumno` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombres` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estado` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `alumno`
--

LOCK TABLES `alumno` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `alumno` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `alumno` VALUES (1,'Elivar Oswaldo','Largo Rios','1'),(5,'Juan','Vargas','1');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `alumno` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2017-12-11 22:53:21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de importar el archivo en phpMyAdmin, simplemente haz click sobre la base de datos en la que quieras crear esta tabla.

También puedes añadir esta línea al principio del fichero .sql que intentas importar:

```
USE cphpmysql;
```

Esto sucede porque el servidor de MySQL aún no sabe con qué base de datos, de entre todas las que gestiona, quieres trabajar. Con esta instrucción o el click se lo indicas.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, realmente me sirvio soy nuevo en esto de xampp asi que no tenia ni idea, me quedo totalmente clara la razon del porque de mi error y pude proseguir sin problemas.